# Can we use same Wizard Styling for Signup as well as inner page Wizard? Different data but same style

Tags: guidelines, ux-designer

I am stuck into two situations: 
I designed the wizard attached below for Signup Purpose but inside dashboard user will be "posting job" and post job has few steps as well. So using the same Wizard for job posting is fine or should I introduce new wizard style?

[image: Sign Wizard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Aim for as few patterns as possible, applied consistently across the application.

Assuming your original design (the Signup wizard) has been tested, and meets the acceptance criteria (success metrics) for your app, you now have a pattern which helps a user:

- navigate a series of meaningful steps and inputs which rely on a specific order (either for implementation purposes/constraints, or to align with a users understanding) to create a new object in the system (an **account** in the first example you have).

Since you've now established a successful implementation of the **[Wizard pattern](http://By%20splitting%20up%20the%20task%20into%20a%20sequence%20of%20chunks,%20each%20of%20which%20can%20be%20dealt%20with%20in%20a%20discrete%20%E2%80%9Cmental%20space%E2%80%9D%20by%20the%20user,%20you%20effectively%20simplify%20the%20task.%20You%20have%20put%20together%20a%20preplanned%20road%20map%20through%20the%20task,%20thus%20sparing%20the%20user%20the%20effort%20of%20figuring%20out%20the%20task%E2%80%99s%20structure%E2%80%94all%20he%20needs%20to%20do%20is%20address%20each%20step%20in%20turn,%20trusting%20that%20if%20he%20follows%20the%20instructions,%20things%20will%20turn%20out%20OK.)**, don't make the user learn another interaction pattern to achieve a similar outcome if possible.

Comment: I completely agree with you sir. But don't you think if user see the same wizard pattern second time when posting a job, they might think this may be an error because the layout structure would be exact same but the content would be different. User will notice layout structure first i guesss than content.

Comment: One thing about ux, is there's no absolute rules :). That said, limiting the interaction models allows users to focus on the the use of similar patterns, so when they go to post, they'll see a series of steps, vertically aligned, where they'll read about which step comes next.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this helps a lot.